# subject object identification in python

Tags: python, spacy

I want to identify subject and objects of a set of sentences . My actual work is to identify cause and effect from a set of review data.

I am using Spacy Package to chunk and parse data. But not actually reaching my goal. Is there any  way to do so?

E.g.:

```
 I thought it was the complete set
```

out:

```
subject  object
I        complete set
```

Answer (score 14):

In the simplest way.
The dependencies are accessed by token.dep_ 
Having imported spacy:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
parsed_text = nlp(u"I thought it was the complete set")

#get token dependencies
for text in parsed_text:
    #subject would be
    if text.dep_ == "nsubj":
        subject = text.orth_
    #iobj for indirect object
    if text.dep_ == "iobj":
        indirect_object = text.orth_
    #dobj for direct object
    if text.dep_ == "dobj":
        direct_object = text.orth_

print(subject)
print(direct_object)
print(indirect_object)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use noun chunk.

### Code

```
doc = nlp("I thought it was the complete set")
for nc in doc.noun_chunks:
    print(nc.text)
```

### Result:

```
I
it
the complete set
```

To pick only "I" instead of both "I" and "it", you can write a test first to take the nsubj left of ROOT.

Answer (score 0):

Stanza is built with highly accurate neural network components that also enable efficient training and evaluation with your own annotated data. The modules are built on top of the PyTorch library.

Stanza is a Python natural language analysis package. It contains tools, which can be used in a pipeline, to convert a string containing human language text into lists of sentences and words, to generate base forms of those words, their parts of speech and morphological features, to give a syntactic structure dependency parse, and to recognize named entities.

```
def find_Subject_Object(text):
    # import required packages
    import stanza
    nlp = stanza.Pipeline(lang='en', processors='tokenize,mwt,pos,lemma,depparse')
    doc = nlp(text)
    clausal_subject = []
    nominal_subject = []
    indirect_object = []
    Object          = []
    for sent in doc.sentences:
        for word in sent.words:
            if word.deprel  == "nsubj":
                nominal_subject.append({word.text:"nominal_subject nsubj"})
            elif word.deprel  == "csubj":
                clausal_subject.append({word.text:"clausal_subject csubj"})
            elif word.deprel  == "iobj":
                indirect_object.append({word.text:"indirect_object iobj"})
            elif word.deprel  == "obj":
                Object.append({word.text:"object obj"})
    return indirect_object, Object, clausal_subject,nominal_subject

text ="""John F. Kennedy International Airport is an international airport in Queens, New York, USA, and one of the primary airports serving New York City."""

find_Subject_Object(text)
# output #
([], [{'City': 'object obj'}], [], [{'John': 'nominal_subject nsubj'}, {'Airport': 'nominal_subject nsubj'}])
```

Stanza includes a Python interface to the CoreNLP Java package and inherits additonal functionality from there, such as constituency parsing, coreference resolution, and linguistic pattern matching.

To summarize, Stanza features:

1. Native Python implementation requiring minimal efforts to set up;
2. Full neural network pipeline for robust text analytics, including tokenization, multi-word token (MWT) expansion, lemmatization, part-of-speech (POS) and morphological features tagging, dependency parsing, and named entity recognition;
3. Pretrained neural models supporting 66 (human) languages;
4. A stable, officially maintained Python interface to CoreNLP.
   [Stanza](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/)