# How to build a Subject-Verb-Object extraction model in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, structure, text-mining, spacy, text-analysis

I have a pandas data frame object with one text column containing one or two sentences of text in each row. I would like to build a Subject-Verb-Object Model to extract the best SVOs from the text column for all the rows.

I am completely new to this, so please do provide additional inputs as to how to proceed.

Thanks!

Comment: [The Stanford Parser](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [subject object identification in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37297399/subject-object-identification-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

create a function and apply to the text column of interest as shown:

```py
import textacy
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
import pandas as pd

def extract_SVOs(text):
    doc = nlp(text)
    tuples = textacy.extract.subject_verb_object_triples(doc)
    return list(tuples)

df['new_column_with_SVOs'] = df['my_text_colum'].apply(extract_SVOs)
```